# MongoDB - How to match a single property value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose a collection contains the following 3 documents:

```
[
  { "_id": 1, "prop": 1 },
  { "_id": 2, "prop": 4 },
  { "_id": 3, "prop": [1, 2, 3] }
]
```

The query `{ $match: { prop: 1 } }` returns 2 documents, namely 1 and 3. I would have expected it to only return 1.

1. Is this behaviour documented somewhere or is it a bug?
2. How could one formulate the query to mean strict equality (as opposed to equality or array-contains)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that MongoDB will always try to match against both scalars and arrays, unless you explicitly rule out the latter:

```
{ $match : { prop : { $eq : 1, $not: { $type : 'array' } } } }
```

It doesn't seem to be explicitly documented, but it's implied in the documentation because the syntax [for querying scalars](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-equality-condition) for a particular value is the same as the syntax [for querying arrays](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element).

Comment: That answers my question #2, but I'm still wondering whether that's documented behaviour.

Comment: @MoB. see edit.

Comment: Interesting. That's an unfortunate overlap in the syntax, especially since the .NET driver translates LINQ queries with `.Contains` into this ambiguous syntax, which could then lead to wrong results.

Answer (score 2):

1. I believe the query returns the document with `_id: 3` is due to [Query an Array for an Element](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element).

The document with `_id: 3` will be fulfilled as there is an element matched in the array.

2. To force strict equality match, I would suggest to provide the aggregation operator in your query, which will [include the checking of type](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/#-eq--aggregation-).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$prop",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the link; that indeed documents the observed behaviour.